# AJAX sign up issue in realtime

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The code below has an issue. Current code doesn't work but if I delete `$.ajax({...` inside **check-main.php**, then everything what I want work.

The point is: Repair `$.ajax({...` which is connected to **check-email.php**.
This `$.ajax({...` should show error like function with password *chkpass = 0;*.

Info: Code below must work in realtime - Detect if email exist on button click onclick="checkStepOne();" and shouldn't remove provided email in input.

**registration.php**

```
  <form method="post" action="" id="frmEmailSignup" onsubmit="return submitResform();">
  <div class="step step-1">
    <section>
      <h1><?=$lang['i_040']?></h1>
      <div class="col-left">
        <p class="prompt"><?=$lang['i_009']?></p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="system/user-login/google.php" id="googlelogin" class="btn-blue googlelogin"><?=$lang['i_011']?></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </li>
          <li style="padding-top: 0px;">
            <a href="system/user-login/microsoft.php" class="btn-blue officelogin" id="officelogin"><?=$lang['i_012']?></a>
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-right">
        <p class="prompt"><?=$lang['i_010']?></p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label class="side-label" for="owner[email]"><?=$lang['i_013']?></label>
            <input type="email" class="email required" id="owner_email" name="owner[email]" placeholder="<?=$lang['i_013']?>" tabindex="0" onkeyup="return forceLower(this);" style="margin-bottom: 6px;"/>
            <?php if ($db->QueryGetNumRows("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='".$login."' OR email='".$email."' LIMIT 1") > 0) { ?>
            <label class="error" style="margin-top: -9px;"><?=$lang['w_024']?></label>
            <?php } else { ?>
                            <label class="error" style="margin-top: -9px;"><?=$lang['i_014']?></label>
            <?php } ?>
            <span class="check"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="password-row">
            <label class="side-label" for="owner[password]"><?=$lang['i_015']?></label>
            <input type="password" class="password required" id="owner_password" name="owner[password]" placeholder="<?=$lang['i_015']?>" tabindex="0"/>
                            <label class="error"><?=$lang['i_016']?></label>
            <span class="check"></span>
          </li>
          <li class="full">
            <button type="button" class="button cta btn-disabled next next-one" tabindex="0" data-plan="register" onclick="checkStepOne();"><?=$lang['i_017']?></button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="step step-2">
    <section>
    <h1><?=$lang['i_018']?></h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" class="password required" id="FirstName" name="owner[FirstName]" placeholder="<?=$lang['i_019']?>" style="width: 48.5%; text-transform: capitalize;"/>
          <input type="text" class="password required" id="LastName" name="owner[LastName]" placeholder="<?=$lang['i_020']?>" style="width: 48.5%; float: right; text-transform: capitalize;"/>
          <label class="error error-w-form"><?=$lang['i_021']?></label>
          <span class="check"></span>
        </li>
      </br>
        <div class="centero" name="gender">
          <fieldset class="material-female" style="margin-right: 20px;">
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="owner[gender]" class="required check-reg" value="female">
              <div class="check">
                <span>
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><line x1="4.5" x2="9.24" y1="12.5" y2="17.24"></line><line x1="9.24" x2="19.76" y1="17.24" y2="6.73"></line></g><g><line x1="4.5" x2="9.24" y1="12.5" y2="17.24"></line><line x1="9.24" x2="19.76" y1="17.24" y2="6.73"></line></g></svg>
                </span>
                <label><?=$lang['i_022']?></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset class="material-male">
            <div>
              <input type="radio" name="owner[gender]" class="required check-reg" value="male">
              <div class="check">
                <span>
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><line x1="4.5" x2="9.24" y1="12.5" y2="17.24"></line><line x1="9.24" x2="19.76" y1="17.24" y2="6.73"></line></g><g><line x1="4.5" x2="9.24" y1="12.5" y2="17.24"></line><line x1="9.24" x2="19.76" y1="17.24" y2="6.73"></line></g></svg>
                </span>
                <label><?=$lang['i_023']?></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <li class="full create">
          <input type="submit" class="button cta next create-account" value="<?=$lang['i_002']?>" name="register"/>
          <p class="agreement"><?=$lang['i_024']?></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <?=$footerLinks?>
  </div>
  </form>
```

**check-main.php**

```
<script>
function forceLower(strInput)  {
  strInput.value=strInput.value.toLowerCase();
}

function checkStepOne() {
  jQuery("#owner_email").parents("li").find("label.error").hide();
  jQuery("#owner_password").parents("li").find("label.error").hide();
  jQuery("#owner_email").parents("li").find("span.check").removeClass('chkValid');
  jQuery("#owner_password").parents("li").find("span.check").removeClass('chkValid');

  var owner_email = jQuery("#owner_email").val();
  var owner_password = jQuery("#owner_password").val();

  var chkemail = 1;
  var chkpass = 1;
  var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

  if (owner_email == "") {
    chkemail = 0;
  }

  if (reg.test(owner_email) == false) {
    chkemail = 0;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check-email.php",
    data: datastring,
    success: function(owner_email) {
      if (owner_email == 0) {
        chkemail == 1;
        jQuery("#owner_email").parents("li").find("span.check").addClass('chkValid');
      } else {
        chkemail == 0;
        jQuery("#owner_email").parents("li").find("label.error").show();
      }
    }
  });

  if (owner_password == "") {
    chkpass = 0;
  }

  if (owner_password.length < 5) {
    chkpass = 0;
  }

  if (chkpass == 1) {
    jQuery("#owner_password").parents("li").find("span.check").addClass('chkValid');
  } else {
    jQuery("#owner_password").parents("li").find("label.error").show();
  }

  if (chkpass == 1 && chkemail == 1) {
    jQuery(".step-1").hide();
    jQuery(".step-2").addClass('chkValid').show();
  }
  return false;
}

function submitResform() {
  var FirstName = jQuery("#FirstName").val();
  var LastName = jQuery("#LastName").val();

  if (FirstName && LastName) {
    return true;
  } else {
    jQuery("#FirstName").parents("li").find("label.error").show();
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

**check-email.php**

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['owner[email]'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) == 1) {
  echo '1';
} else {
  echo '0';
}
?>
```

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for this long code. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: `data: datastring,`  -  I don't see `datastring` defined anywhere. I'd imagine this error is appearing in your developer console (F12) as well.

Comment: @TylerRoper What should I write inside `data: datastring,`? If you're know the answer. Write below and I will approve.